# Storage for Big Blue Button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-14.04, bigbluebutton

I have the following doubts for storage in BBB recordings:

1. Where is the recording being stored?

   - I saw that its stored in /var/bigbluebutton folder on the server where BBB is installed. But there are many folders there. Which is the exact folder I should look for?
2. How much space is allotted for storage?

   - Is it the same space that I have for my server since my recordings are stored on the server itself?
3. Other than the user deleting the recording, how long are recordings stored? Should we have a job that is scheduled to remove them? (We do not anticipate needing to save them in definitely, perhaps just for the semester.)

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the API to get the recording if possible, instead of looking for files on server
http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#recording